# MongoDB Atlas doesn't appear in my Linked Services list in Azure Data Factory 2

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-data-factory, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to create a service link for Atlas mongodb in Microsoft Azure Data Factory v2.

According to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-mongodb-atlas) now we can copy data from MongoDB Atlas using Azure Data Factory 2.

I can find mongodb connection but not the one from Atlas.

I searched my Linked Services list but MongoDB Atlas doesn't appear anywhere.

How can I get this up ?

Does it any thing to have with the region or the cloud servers location?

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This week I tried again and now it appears in my list.

It seems like the updates was not propagated in our servers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bug, something for Azure to resolve. I got it listed in numerous of regions, US East being one of them. Can you create a new ADF in US East, setup MongoDB Atlas linked service with the necessary connection strings then output the configuration via JSON.

Then try running Az to create the linked service inside the ADF that you need, with properties value set from the previous linked service created - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/datafactory/datafactory/linked-service?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_datafactory_az_datafactory_linked_service_create

Then just drop the newly created ADF.